# Deploying AWS Cloudwatch dashboards with the CDK: how do I hide metrics

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, dashboard, aws-cdk

I have a custom metric that I push updates to in my code. In the CDK, I have created a derived metric from this custom metric. I would like the derived metric to show up in the dashboard but the original metric to be hidden. How can I achieve this?

Here is my cut-down (TypeScript) CDK code which deploys successfully:

```
  const createDashboard = (scope: cdk.Construct, namespace: string, statistic = Statistic.AVERAGE) => {
  const customDynamoLatencyMetric: IMetric = new Metric({
    period: Duration.minutes(1),
    metricName: 'MY_DYNAMO_LATENCY_METRIC',
    namespace,
    statistic,
  });

  const derivedAverageDynamoLatencyMetric = new MathExpression({
    expression: 'm1/1000', label: 'To Dynamo Latency', usingMetrics: { m1: customDynamoLatencyMetric }, period: Duration.minutes(1),
  });

  const dashboard = new Dashboard(
    scope,
    'myDashboard', {
      dashboardName: 'myDashboard',
    },
  );

  const widget = new GraphWidget({
    title: 'Average Latency',
    left: [customDynamoLatencyMetric, derivedAverageDynamoLatencyMetric],
    view: GraphWidgetView.TIME_SERIES,
    region: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION,
    width: 12,
  });

  dashboard.addWidgets(widget);
};
```

If I manually mark this metric as invisible in the AWS Cloudwatch Dasgboard Console then when I view/edit source in the Cloudwatch Console I see the following:

```
"metrics": [
                    [ "stephenburns-gcs-pipeline", "DYNAMO_LATENCY", { "id": "m1", "visible": false } ],
                    [ { "label": "To Dynamo Latency", "expression": "m1/1000", "period": 60, "id": "e1", "region": "ap-southeast-2" } ]
            ]
```

My question is how do I get that **"visible": false** property via the CDK?

I tried using the Metric's dimensions property e.g.

```
dimensions: { visible: false }
```

but it fails at deployment time with the error: *"Invalid metric field type, only "String" type is allowed"*

Does anyone know how to mark a metric as initially invisible?

Answer (score 3):

If you only add the original `Metric` to the `usingMetrics` property of the `MathExpression` and don't add it directly to the `GraphWidget`, the CDK appears to automatically set `visible` to false. The [CDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-cloudwatch.Metric.html) does not currently (as of version 1.123.0) indicate a way to set the visibility of a `Metric` directly.

In the code example you provided, this would simply require changing the line:

```
left: [customDynamoLatencyMetric, derivedAverageDynamoLatencyMetric],
```

to:

```
left: [customDynamoLatencyMetric],
```